# SSIS: The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssis, configuration-files

I'm trying to update my ETL jobs on a new reporting server and I got this error:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016
>   Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:44:21 PM  Error:
>   2016-12-28 15:44:22.24     Code: 0xC0209303     Source: FactCOGS
>   Connection manager "MyConnection"     Description: The requested OLE
>   DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not
>   installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An
>   OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service
>   Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
>   End Error  Error: 2016-12-28 15:44:22.24     Code: 0xC020F42A
>   Description:
>   Consider changing the PROVIDER in the connection string to SQLNCLI11
>   or visit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads to find and install
>   support for SQLNCLI10.1.  End Error  Error: 2016-12-28 15:44:22.24
>   Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Load Stage OLE DB Source [149]

I tried changing the provider in my config file to **SQLNCLI11** as it suggests which seemed to fix the problem for others but I am still getting the same error.

**Drivers on report server:**

[image]

Comment: Jonathan, looks like the necessary sql server drivers are not installed. SQLNCLI10 and SQLNCLI11 are connectivity drivers for SQL Server (introduced in SQL Server 2008 and 2012 respectively). Is there a reason you were looking at Access to fix this? Verify if your new machine has the SQLNCLI10 or SQLNCLI11 drivers installed or not. I usually look at the ODBC admin utility to see what drivers are available,

Comment: Sam, thank you for the help! I checked the drivers and SQLNCLI11 is installed and I changed the config file to use SQLNCLI11 as the provider but the same exact error occurs saying "The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered."

Comment: Then I would check if the driver info is being overridden? When you say config file, what are providing thru the config file? Make sure that the Provider part of the connection string gets changed to the new driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to finish this today so I ended up installing the SQLNCLI10 drivers on the new report server and everything worked again. If I find a better solution in the future I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error after adding a exporting a package from one solution to another solution. I was able to resolve the Error by `open the solution in visual Studio -> open connection(s) used in the package -> test connection(s).`

I re-ran the the package and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the job step. Go to "Execution options". Try checking "Use 32 bit runtime" option.

Comment: Can you please tell in details? I have same error and my SSIS package is not in SQL DB Catalog. It uses package config file where I have setup SQL DB connection which uses SQL Native Client SQLNCLI11.1.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message running a SSIS DTSX Package created on Visual Studio 2008 and deployed on SQL Server 10.50.6560. I fixed the problem by going to the SSIS Solution Properties -> Debugging -> Debug Options -> Run64BitRuntime -> Set to **TRUE**. It workout just fine, hope it helps.